Downloading image via a blob:https
I'm trying to download images which are at an url such as blob:https://, however using requests and urllib does not work. Both of them crash when making the request. urllib gives the error code "" and requests gives "No connection adapters were found for "blob"".

Not sure why you are downloading image via link? you can download image from blob if you have connection string just provide the path and download it from blob. you will find plenty options and code out there.

The blob URLs are not actual URLs that can be directly accesse using libraries like requests or urllib. These URLs are typically used by browsers to represent binary data, such as files or media, that has been loaded into memory. These blob URLs are created in the browser and are not accessible outside of the browser's context.
So only way to access them would be probably JavaScript or something similar.
